# Android permission denied on rooted device

Tags: android, permissions

Not sure why, but I can't run an APK after I've downloaded it onto a rooted device.. Any ideas? I am trying to create an auto-updater for our in-house app but I can't get it to work!

```
06-19 11:52:45.426 W/ActivityManager(  486): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{424b6658 u0 ttt.ttt/tablettimeclock.MainActivity}
06-19 11:52:45.446 I/ActivityManager(  486): Start proc com.android.packageinstaller for activity com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity: pid=1281 uid=10044 gids={50044, 1028}
06-19 11:52:45.466 D/dalvikvm(  131): GC_EXPLICIT freed 40K, 3% free 7279K/7464K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 27ms
06-19 11:52:45.486 D/dalvikvm(  131): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 3% free 7279K/7464K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 22ms
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/zipro   ( 1281): Unable to open zip '/data/user/0/ttt.ttt/files/ttt.apk': Permission denied
06-19 11:52:45.486 D/asset   ( 1281): failed to open Zip archive '/data/user/0/ttt.ttt/files/ttt.apk'
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageInstaller( 1281): Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/user/0/ttt.ttt/files/ttt.apk
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:455)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:509)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageUtil.getPackageInfo(PackageUtil.java:73)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity.onCreate(PackageInstallerActivity.java:511)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-19 11:52:45.486 W/PackageParser( 1281):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You either are installing app in a wrong way or the whole project has wrong structure. Try: android tools -> fix project properties or the well-known approach - clean - build

Comment: Uh, don't think I have that option in Xamarin (forgot to mention it is in Xamarin!)...

Comment: Maybe it's just that the OS can't access that folder (`/data/user/0/ttt.ttt/files/`)?

Comment: Possibly.. but I can't for the life of me figure out a place where it can! I have rooted the device, so I thought it would work anywhere? I have also tried /data/data/ and /sdcard/data/ and both get permission denied

Comment: Do I need to make it a system app? And is that possible with Xamarin/Monodroid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out eventually.

```
Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).ToString()
```

That gets you to a place it will work.

Thanks for your help.

Le-roy

Answer (score 0):

Rooting the device doesn't automatically open up everything - directory and file permissions are still applied against processes based on the 'user' they run as.

Options:

- Install a file manager app that is root aware and use it to move the apk file to somewhere more normal, like the downloads folder.
- Use ADB to move the file somewhere more accessible.

Comment: Yes it is the answer but could you please give us: "How To"